# Updating Api Versions for VF pages Apex Classes as Versions 21.0 through 30.0 of the Salesforce Platform are not supported

Tags: apex, visualforce, api-version

My organization is trying to update API versions or more than 100 Apex classes, Test classes and VF pages from older versions (19-30) to newer versions. It's a mammoth task to check and test every class and VF page if the functionality is working without any issue after the update.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Do you have unit tests, automation tests, end-to-end tests...?

Comment: This API retirement applies to SOAP, REST and Bulk APIs only, and not Apex, as covered in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&type=1).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you've run out of time. We've known about this since [October 2019](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380623&type=1), so you've had over three years to fix things. You do have another few months left, so it's time to get started.

I would recommend a gradual approach. First, set everything to version 28.0, and see if it deploys. This is a major hurdle, because that had a number of breaking changes, but there's no need to fix anything if you don't get any compile errors.

Next, I'd suggest 32.0, and this time run all unit tests. If nothing breaks, you're *probably* okay, if your unit tests are decent. The only real major changes to worry about are related to JSON. If you don't use it, don't worry about it.

After that, you can try version 38.0. There were some interesting bugs here, so run all tests again. If you get this far, it's probably safe to move everything to 56.0. If you get this far, then do just one giant test.

Yes, it's going to take time, probably weeks, but you've had three years to fix this, so there's not much to be said at this point but to get a move on. You may want to consider hiring some consultants, and salesforce.com themselves also offer consulting services. Time is money, and you've already squandered quite a bit of time, so now you need to spend some money to make up for it.

Don't worry about a massive test until the end, because most of the breaking changes between the lower APIs and 48.0 will likely be caught even if you only have code-coverage-only smoke tests.

Comment: The document you reference covers retirement of API versions 7 through 20, not 21 through 30. Indeed, 21 through 30 retirement is for REST, SOAP and Bulk APIs only, not Apex, as covered [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389618&type=1). That said, it probably makes sense to spend some time getting VF pages and Apex classes to newer versions anyway. Just not necessary for Summer '23.